# While submitting the form i am getting the page not found in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am new to codeigniter. While submitting the form i am getting 404 error page not found.Actually without entering the username and password it should work the valudations. Here is the code.

> login.php in controller

```
public function verifyuser()
        {

          $this->load->library('form_validation');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','username','required');
          $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required');

          if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            $this->load->view('login/login');
        }else{
        $this->load->model('login/validate');
        }
        }
```

****login/login.php****

```
<?php echo form_open('verifyuser'); ?>
    <!--  start login-inner -->
    <div id="login-inner">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <td><input type="text" name="username"  class="login-inp" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Password</th>
            <td><input type="password" name="password" value="************"  onfocus="this.value=''" class="login-inp" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-size" id="login-check" /><label for="login-check">Remember me</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td><input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit-login"  /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: The answer is *login/login.php*

<?php echo form_open('login/verifyuser'); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're intending to submit to the same controller you're on, you don't need to specify anything in `form_open`:

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
...
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This should be enough. CI will automatically use the current controller/method when nothing is specified. Furthermore, the reason you're getting the error is because you're telling `form_open` that you want to load the controller/method `verifyuser/index`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call form_open function with parameter like `controller/function`.